# How to update one field from all documents using POJO in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this `Student` POJO class:

```
public class Student {
    private String name, rollNumber;
    private boolean active;

    public Student() {
        //For Firebase
    }

    public Student(String name, String rollNumber, boolean active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getRollNumber() {
        return rollNumber;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

This is my database:

```
student-xxxxx
   -students
       -uid
         - name
         - rollNumber
         - active
```

There are 100 students, some are active and some are not. I want to make all students not active.

Code:

```
db.collection("students").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Student student = document.toObject(Student.class);
                // How to update???
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How to update `active` to false using POJO? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this, in a very simple way. Beside the getter, you should also create a setter for your `active` property like this:

```
public void setActive(boolean active) {
    this.active = active;
}
```

Once you have created the setter, you can use it directly on your `student` object like this:

```
db.collection("students").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Student student = document.toObject(Student.class);
                student.setActive(false); //Use the setter
                String id = document.getId();
                db.collection("students").document(id).set(student); //Set student object
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result of this code would be to update the active property of all you student objects to `false` and set the updated object right on the corresponding reference.