# Cloud Firestore Update

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like update document in cloud firestore according to value in document. Something like this. I have few documents with random names and values and one document with values  `id = 1` , `name = patryk` . And now I'd to update document with `name=patryk`. And I don't know document name because I make them like this and they have a random name.

```
b.collection("Users")
    .add(postMapa)
    .addOnCompleteListener
```

How to do this? [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) I need have the name of the document but I don't have.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this and make sure there will be only single document for name = patryk**

```
  db.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("name", "patryk").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    String documentId = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().get(0).getId();
                   // here you have id but make sure you have only one document for name=patryk
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `id` property is of type number and the `name` property is of type String, please use the following code in order to update all users with the `id = 1` and `name = patryk`:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("Users").whereEqualTo("id", 1).whereEqualTo("name", "patryk");
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                list.add(document.getId());
            }

            for (String id : list) {
                rootRef.collection("Users").document(id).update("name", "New Name").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Name Updated!");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you are using a model class for your user, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179367/how-to-update-one-field-from-all-documents-using-pojo-in-firestore)**.

Answer (score 0):

you can retrieve documents by their name (which does not really apply here):

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document("patryk");
```

or you can query for values contained in a document (which might answer your question):

```
/* create a reference to the Users collection */
CollectionReference users = db.collection("Users");

/* create a query against the collection */
Query query = users.whereEqualTo("name", "patryk");
```

the rest is the same procedure, in both cases:

```
/* asynchronously retrieve the document */
ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();

/* future.get() blocks on response */
DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();

if (document.exists()) {
    System.out.println("Document data: " + document.getData());
} else {
    System.out.println("No such document!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get all `document id` under the collections:

```
firebase.collection("Users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                list.add(document.getId());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, list.toString());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```